# Lenovo thinkpad dock USB charge

Tags: thinkpad

I've got a Lenovo 90W Pro Dock, looking for a way to have my USB port to charge my mobile phones when my laptop is off. Basically I am trying to have it perform like a USB charger. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in product description on the official Lenovo site, one of the USB ports is always-on, so yes, it is possible: 
https://www3.lenovo.com/us/en/accessories-and-monitors/docking/mechanical-docks/ThinkPad-Pro-Dock-90W/p/40A10090US